# reactJS app with a fetch to an API fails to load with No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, cors, fetch

I have the following code which worked 6 days ago:

```
            function showProduct(barcode) {

            let url = "https://api.barcodelookup.com/v2/products?barcode=" + barcode + "&key=mj1pm32ylcctxj1byaiaxxxxxxxxxx";
            const options = { method: 'GET' };                
            fetch(url, options)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(myJson) {
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                if (myJson == undefined) 
                {
                    console.log("fetch failed")
                } 
                else 
                {
                    //inspect the data that the WebAPI returned
                    console.log("myJson: ", myJson);
                    console.log(myJson.products[0].barcode_formats);                        
                    Quagga.stop();   
                }
                }, 3000);
            });
        }
```

and the value being passed into the function is 5000159459228.  When I executed this code last week, I was receiving a response back from the API and I was able to pick up the individual fields being returned.

Today, I started debugging a different feature of my app and now I receive this error when executing the above listed code:

> Failed to load https://api.barcodelookup.com/v2/products?barcode=5000159459228&key=mj1pm32ylcctxj1byaiaxxxxxxxxxx: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

followed by this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

and then this:

> newscan:91 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://api.barcodelookup.com/v2/products?barcode=5000159459228&key=mj1pm32ylcctxj1byaiaxxxxxxxxxx with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

If I manually paste the string that I build into the url variable into a browser, I do get a valid response back.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan what you have there is a `cors` problem. A quick way to solve that if you are using express in your backend is just add CORS module with `npm i --save cors` and then use it as a middleware:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

You can always add the headers yourself. Take a deepr look at [Enable CORS.org](https://enable-cors.org/)

Your question was also answered here: [[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe?rq=1])

Comment: I changed the url from https://api.barcodelookup.com/v2/products?barcode=5000159459228&key=mj1pm32ylcctxj1byaiaxxxxxxxxxx to https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.barcodelookup.com/v2/products?barcode=5000159459228&key=mj1pm32ylcctxj1byaiaxxxxxxxxxx.  I still get this error "Failed to load https://api.barcodelookup.com/v2/products?barcode=5000159459228&key=mj1pm32ylcctxj1byaiaxxxxxxxxxx: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Dont ask me why, but it's working now.  very strange.  Thanks for your help.